# My grass only shows one side of color

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I tried to follow this tutorial on how to make grass: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GAm-7_3N6g&t=507s&ab_channel=CGGeek
And i chosed to color my grass blue/purple ish, but it only shows on one side? I dunno what i did worng, I followed the video (which is kind of old), but it's green on the other side. What did I do wrong?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Rebecca, welcome to Blender.SE. I can't see anytingh strange from your screenshots. Could you upload your file (remember to pack the textures) to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? Are you using eevee, right? not blender internal